# Is there a way to use vectorization in place of this nested for loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this current (working as designed) nested for-loop that grabs some data of interest and creates a pandas dataframe from it. In an effort to cut down on runtime, I have been trying to figure out if vectorization could be a good replacement for the nested for-loop. Is there any way to vectorize these loops?

```
for i, row in enumerate(ldamodel[corpus]):
        row = sorted(row, key=lambda x: (x[1]), reverse=True)
        # Get the Dominant topic, % Contribution and Keywords for each document
        for j, (topic_num, prop_topic) in enumerate(row):
            if j == 0:  # Pull dominant topic
                wp = ldamodel.show_topic(topic_num)
                topic_keywords = ", ".join([word for word, prop in wp])
                sent_topics_df = sent_topics_df.append(pd.Series([int(topic_num), ldamodel.get_document_topics(corpus[i]), topic_keywords]), ignore_index=True)
            else:
                break
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic, and add a [mcve] ?

Comment: Not sure of an easy way to add a reproducible example, but the jist is that I am working with a gensim LDAMultiCore object, and am trying to extract the dominant topic, the % contribution to each topic, and the keywords for that topic, out of the object and into the new dataframe